# Insert comma between digits in vim using regex (recover csv file whose commas were filtered)

Tags: regex, string, csv, vim, sed

I have a `.csv` file such as this below:

```
abcde
12345
1.523.545.5
```

I would like to use a `%s/<regex>/<subs>/g` to change the file into this (which means, one digit number possibly followed by a `.` and another one digit number):

```
a, b, c, d, e
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1.5, 2, 3.5, 4, 5.5
```

I tried `%s/\(\w\)[^\.]/\1, /g` to match only digits that is *NOT* followed by a `.` but I am getting this:

```
a, c, e
1, 3, 5
1.5, 3.5, 5.5
```

I am not sure why I have deleted out `b` and `d` columns. I am close but not there yet. Any clues?

Comment: pls explain why `1.523.545.5` could be changed into `1, 2.5, 3, 4.5, 5`

Comment: It looks like the decimal is being placed AFTER the integer: `.52` should actually be `2.5` so the order of those values need to be reversed. `1.523.545.5` is actually `1` then `.52` then `3` then `.54` then `5` then `.5` and each of those `.52` should become `2.5` so: `1` `2.5` `3` `4.5` `5` and then some trailing `.5` or maybe it's supposed to be `5.0` ?

Comment: @OnlineCop from the title : `(recover csv file whose commas were filtered)` I guess OP gave a wrong input (precisely speaking, the last line). However I am not sure

Comment: Updated a typo in the original post. It was 5.5 not 4.5. Thanks @Kent

Comment: @OnlineCop I am sorry for the confusion. I made a very bad typo in the post. Please check it out now.

Comment: @hyiltiz good, then I can post my answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a zero width match, in vim what you need is `\@!`.  `:h zero-width` to check details.

In vim this line should work for your input example:

```
%s/\v\w([.].|$)@!/&, /g
```

or

```
%s/\v\w(\.\d|$)@!/&, /g
```

It gives the expected output:

```
a, b, c, d, e
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1.5, 2, 3.5, 4, 5.5
```

Comment: Any way to simplify this, possibly without using `zero-width` matching? I read the help page on that twice, but seems far more complicated. If it is impossible to simplify due to how regex is constructed, could you please elaborate what necessitates it? Thanks! E.g. I thought you could write `foo[^(bar)]` to mean any `foo` not followed by `bar`. But the help page says that is what `\@!` does.

Comment: @hyiltiz read `:h \@!` there you will find an example, I think it is pretty clear.

Comment: Would not one be using `[^(nomatch)]` for that?

Comment: @hyiltiz `y(x)@!` will match only `y` (without `a`) from string `ya`, however `y[^x]` will match `ya`

Answer (score 2):

Another Vim solution:

```
:%s/\v\w(\.\d)?\zs\ze\w/, /g
```

Output:

```
a, b, c, d, e                                   
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1.5, 2, 3.5, 4, 5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT due to OP update**

You should just be able to look for "any `\w` character" and then, if a `.` character is found, look for `.\d`. If it is not found, skip it (you can do this by using `(\.\d)?` like this:

```
(\w)(\.\d)?
```

and simply replaced with

```
\1\2,
```

https://regex101.com/r/vK4iE7/2

However, this is not VIM-formatted, so you may need to look into others' answers to see how to format this correctly.

https://regex101.com/r/vK4iE7/3 additionally leaves off the trailing comma.

**OLD**

Do you want the output to look similar to https://regex101.com/r/vK4iE7/1 where the '.' and the value after it are actually part of the number following that?

Granted, this isn't in VIM formatting (it's PCRE), but I want to ensure that I've got the logic correct:

Searching for

```
(\.\d)?(\w)
```

and replaced with

```
\2\1,
```

turns

```
abcde
12345
1.523.545.5
```

into

```
a,b,c,d,e,
1,2,3,4,5,
1,2.5,3,4.5,5,.5,
```

which, unfortunately, does have those trailing commas, and that last `.5` in the bottom line.

Comment: Sorry I had a bad input in the original post. Actually the reverse positioning `\1\2` is not necessary, and the reverse matching. Could you please update?

Comment: Accepting the answer using Vim, since it fits better in this situation (also without the trailing last comma).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
%s/\(\.[[:digit:]]\)\=\(\w\)/\2\1,/g
```

which uses the vi regex formatting.

Comment: For some reason, the last 5.5 is not properly processed.
a,b,c,d,e,
1,2,3,4,5,
1,2.5,3,4.5,5,.5,

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\B/, /g' file
```